# coordinate geometry : intersection of a curve with a line

Tags: coordinate-systems

I'm having difficulties with the question below. It is from a Cambridge past paper.

> The equation of a curve is $xy=12$ and the equation of a line $l$ is $2x+y=k$, where $k$ is a constant. In the case where $k=10$, one of the points of intersection is $P(2,6)$. Find the angle, in degrees correct to $1$ decimal place, between $l$ and the tangent to the curve at $P$."

I know the answer is $8.1$ degrees and the method to find the answer is either by using differentiation or by using the fact that $\text{gradient}=\tan(\theta)$.

Thank you

Comment: Hint: The line with equation $y = mx + b$ makes angle $\theta = \arctan m$ with the rightward-pointing $x$-axis.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use both differentiation and the fact that the gradient$=\tan(\theta)$. For the curve you have:$$xy=12\implies y=12x^{-1}$$Differentiate this to find the gradient of the tangent line at $x=2$.
The line is given by:$$2x+y=10$$So you should know what its gradient is equal to.

Lets call the angle that the line makes with the x-axes $\alpha$ and the angle that the tangent to the curve makes with the x-axes $\beta$. We therefore know the values of $\tan(\alpha)$ and $\tan(\beta)$ since these are equal to the gradients of the line and the tangent to the curve at $x=2$.

You now just need to use the angle difference formula:$$\tan(\alpha-\beta)=\frac{\tan(\alpha)-\tan(\beta)}{1+\tan(\alpha)\tan(\beta)}$$to work out the tan of the angle between these two. Then find the arctan of this value to finally give you the angle between them.